# fs.createWriteStream to fs.createReadStream

Tags: node.js, stream, sox

I'm using a node.js module `sox-audio` to trim mp3 audio for streaming.
From this [example](https://github.com/psaylor/sox-audio/blob/master/examples/trim.js) -

```
var SoxCommand = require('sox-audio');

var trimFileAndPipeExample = function(inputFile, startTimeSeconds, endTimeSeconds, outputPipe) {
    var startTimeFormatted = TimeFormat.formatTimeAbsolute(startTimeSeconds);
    var endTimeFormatted = TimeFormat.formatTimeAbsolute(endTimeSeconds);

    var command = SoxCommand()
        .input(inputFile)
        .output(outputPipe)
        .outputFileType('wav')
        .trim(startTimeFormatted, endTimeFormatted)
        .run();
    return command;
}
```

In order to assign an output, you use - `fs.createWriteStream('./output.mp3');`

So

```
var outputPipe = fs.createWriteStream('./output.mp3');

trimFileAndPipeExample(inputFile, startTime, endTime, outputPipe);
```

Creates the output file.

What I want to do is grab the output and direct it to `fs.createReadStream` from a request which I got with -

```
var outputPipe = fs.createWriteStream('./test.mp3');

trim(path, startTime, endTime, outputPipe);

outputPipe.on('finish', () => {
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream('./test.mp3');
    readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

But I don't necessarily want to have to create the file everytime but instead direct the data to `fs.createReadStream`.

Is there a way to rewrite `fs.createWriteStream` so that it doesn't require an output path and just `.pipe` it directly to fs.createReadStream right away?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since Express `res` is already a Writable Stream, you can pass it to `trimFileAndPipeExample` directly.

```
router.get('/cut', function (req, res, next) {
  var inputFile = './assets/utterance_0.wav';
  var startTime = 1;
  var endTime = 5;
  res.set('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
  trimFileAndPipeExample(inputFile, startTime, endTime, res);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! One last question if you don't mind answering. Will sox or the processing be able to handle let's say a million requests at the same time?

Comment: This is not a problem of sox, search google for `scale node js application` for  a solution.